# Fatal error allowed memory exhausted when looping with conditional statement

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, conditional-statements

```
<?php
$array = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100];
$result = [];
for ($i=0; $i < count($array) ; $i++) { 
    if (($i >=3 AND $i <= 6) OR $i=8){
        array_push($result, $array[$i]*2);
    } else {
        array_push($result, $array[$i]*10);
    }
}
var_dump($result);
?>
```

I want to multiply value in array that have key 3, 4, 5, 6, and 8 by 2, other than that key I want to multiply it by 10.

Tried change memory limit even to -1 (unlimited) but still give same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the only problem is: you are changing the value of **$i** inside the **if** clause because of a missing **=**, it should be **$i==8** instead of **$i=8**, a working script with some minor changes would be:

```
<?php
    $array = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100];
    $result = [];
    $length = count($array);
    for($i=0; $i < $length ; $i++) { 
        if (($i >=3 AND $i <= 6) OR $i==8){
            $val = $array[$i] * 2;        
        } else {
            $val = $array[$i] * 10;
        }
        array_push($result, $val);
    }
    // output
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

This outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 200
    [2] => 300
    [3] => 80
    [4] => 100
    [5] => 120
    [6] => 140
    [7] => 800
    [8] => 180
    [9] => 1000
)
```

Answer (score 1):

change your if condition from: `if (($i >=3 AND $i <= 6) OR $i=8){`

to : `if (($i >=3 AND $i <= 6) OR $i==8){`

***You are not assigning a value to $i. You are checking its value. That's why you must use `==`.